# Sitecore 9.3 output cache VaryByCustom

Tags: caching

In `Sitecore 9.3` solution I've got a few MVC controllers returning JSON data. I was planning on using the standard `ASP.NET MVC OutputCache` attribute which works absolutely fine. However, I also require implementing the custom vary by logic, which typically is implemented in `Global.asax` `GetVaryByCustomString` method.

Quick investigation shown me that `Global.asax` file is no longer a part of Solution in `Sitecore 9.3`. In this case, where can I put my `GetVaryByCustomString` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is not recommended to modify `Global.asax` file in Sitecore solutions. This is because Sitecore has its own implementation of `Global.asax` and changing the file may cause problems during Sitecore version upgrade.
In order to allow some flexibility in common `Global.asax` methods, Sitecore provides a set of pipelines such as `<initialize>` and `<sessionEnd>`, however there is no pipeline for `GetVaryByCustomString`.

If `GetVaryByCustomString` is critical for your solution, you can create a class and inherit it from `Sitecore.Web.Application`:

```
public class CustomApplication : Sitecore.Web.Application
{
    public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
    {
        //add your logic here
    }
}
```

Then you can reference the class in `Global.asax` and make sure it gets deployed to your website root folder:

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="YourNamespace.CustomApplication" %>
```

Please note that ASP.NET MVC output cache will not be cleared by Sitecore event handlers so it is only suitable for caching data coming from external sources, for example third-party APIs. If your data is managed within Sitecore, the best approach would be to utilise Sitecore cache layers.

Answer (score 2):

The usual place to put cache key generation logic is `mvc.renderRendering` pipeline, where you should be able to replace `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.GenerateCacheKey, Sitecore.Mvc` processor. Or add your own processor after `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.GenerateCacheKey, Sitecore.Mvc` that will be able to change `args.CacheKey`.

Comment: Hi Anton! Thanks for your suggestion, however I do not have rendering for this controller method returning JSON at all. It is just a simple MVC controller returning JsonResult, and a standard MVC output cache, which I guess is different from Sitecore rendering output cache.